# Http post and get request in angular 6

Tags: httprequest, observable, angular6

In angular 5.2.x for http get and post I had this code:

```
post(url: string, model: any): Observable<boolean> {

return this.http.post(url, model)
  .map(response => response)
  .do(data => console.log(url + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
  .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
 }
 get(url: string): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get(url)
  .map(response => response)
  .do(data =>
    console.log(url + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data))
  )
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(this.handleError(error)));
 }
```

In angular 6 it doesn't work.

How can we make an HTTP post or get request?

Comment: I recommend you this article. It contains your problem - changes from DO to TAP - and more. https://alligator.io/angular/angular-6/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Update :
In angular 7, they are the same as 6

In angular 6

the complete answer found in [live example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ooqemvjyqkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.ts)

```
  /** POST: add a new hero to the database */
  addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
 return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
  );
}
  /** GET heroes from the server */
 getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
  );
}
```

it's because of `pipeable/lettable operators` which now angular is able to use `tree-shakable` and remove unused imports and optimize the app

some rxjs functions are changed

```
do -> tap
catch -> catchError
switch -> switchAll
finally -> finalize
```

more in [MIGRATION](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)

**and Import paths**

For JavaScript developers, the general rule is as follows:

rxjs: Creation methods, types, schedulers and utilities

```
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
```

rxjs/operators: All pipeable operators:

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

rxjs/webSocket: The web socket subject implementation

```
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
```

rxjs/ajax: The Rx ajax implementation

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
```

rxjs/testing: The testing utilities

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
```

and for backward compatability you can use `rxjs-compat`

Comment: It would help if you could repeat the gist of linked content here. Just to keep this Q&A self contained, less susceptible to link rot.

Comment: link for RxJS v6   [ReactiveX/rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Comment: is there any difference between AJAX call & http.post/get calling in angular 6?

Comment: @UmeshPatadiya No they are the same. because http.post/get .. are using  the XMLHttpRequest interface . https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: is there any way to get faster response from http.post/get requests?

Comment: What do you mean by faster? Is it slow?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a **post/get** using a library which allows you to **use HttpClient with strongly-typed callbacks**.

The data and the error are available directly via these callbacks.

The library is called **angular-extended-http-client**.

[**angular-extended-http-client library on GitHub**](https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/angular-http-client-ext)

[**angular-extended-http-client library on NPM**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-extended-http-client)

Very easy to use.

### Traditional approach

In the traditional approach you return Observable<`HttpResponse<`T`>`> from Service API. This is tied to HttpResponse.

With this approach you have to use **.subscribe(x => ...)** in the rest of your code.

This creates a **tight coupling** between the **http layer** and the **rest of your code**.

### Strongly-typed callback approach

You only deal with your Models in these strongly-typed callbacks.

Hence, The rest of your code only knows about your Models.

#### Sample usage

The strongly-typed callbacks are

Success:

- **IObservable<`T`>**
- **IObservableHttpResponse**
- **IObservableHttpCustomResponse<`T`>**

Failure:

- **IObservableError<`TError`>**
- **IObservableHttpError**
- **IObservableHttpCustomError<`TError`>**

#### Add package to your project and in your app module

```js
import { HttpClientExtModule } from 'angular-extended-http-client';
```

and in the @NgModule imports

```js
  imports: [
    .
    .
    .
    HttpClientExtModule
  ],
```

#### Your Models

```js
export class SearchModel {
    code: string;
}

//Normal response returned by the API.
export class RacingResponse {
    result: RacingItem[];
}

//Custom exception thrown by the API.
export class APIException {
    className: string;
}
```

#### Your Service

In your Service, you just create params with these callback types.

Then, pass them on to the **HttpClientExt**'s get method.

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core'
import { SearchModel, RacingResponse, APIException } from '../models/models'
import { HttpClientExt, IObservable, IObservableError, ResponseType, ErrorType } from 'angular-extended-http-client';
.
.

@Injectable()
export class RacingService {

    //Inject HttpClientExt component.
    constructor(private client: HttpClientExt, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig) {

    }

    //Declare params of type IObservable<T> and IObservableError<TError>.
    //These are the success and failure callbacks.
    //The success callback will return the response objects returned by the underlying HttpClient call.
    //The failure callback will return the error objects returned by the underlying HttpClient call.
    searchRaceInfo(model: SearchModel, success: IObservable<RacingResponse>, failure?: IObservableError<APIException>) {
        let url = this.config.apiEndpoint;

        this.client.post<SearchModel, RacingResponse>(url, model, 
                                                      ResponseType.IObservable, success, 
                                                      ErrorType.IObservableError, failure);
    }
}
```

#### Your Component

In your Component, your Service is injected and the **searchRaceInfo** API called as shown below.

```js
  search() {    


    this.service.searchRaceInfo(this.searchModel, response => this.result = response.result,
                                                  error => this.errorMsg = error.className);

  }
```

Both, **response** and **error** returned in the callbacks are strongly typed. Eg. **response** is type **RacingResponse** and **error** is **APIException**.

Answer (score 0):

For reading full response in Angular you should add the observe option:

```
{ observe: 'response' }
```

```
    return this.http.get(`${environment.serverUrl}/api/posts/${postId}/comments/?page=${page}&size=${size}`, { observe: 'response' });
```