# Angular 6 http response failure for localhost:4200 while doing post request

Tags: post, angular6

While making a post request via Angular 6 it is saying:

> http failure response 404 error

Comment: Did check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196282/http-post-and-get-request-in-angular-6

Comment: Well, it seems like the backend that you query either does not have any resources or you specify a wrong link. If you share some code with us we could help you, without code there unfortunately are a million problems that may cause this behavior.