# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm newbie for the angular. And current I'm learning angular 6 features.
When I try to handle error there is some issues like,

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/observable/throw' in
>   'D:\WORKSPACE\Angular5\binding\src\app'
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/catch' in
>   'D:\WORKSPACE\Angular5\binding\src\app'
>
> ERROR in src/app/employee.service.ts(20,14): error TS2339: Property
>   'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Here is my employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEmployee } from './employee';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

//It self injectable defendency.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private _url: string = "/assets/data/employees.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);                    
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){
      return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");
  }
}
```

employee.ts

```
export interface IEmployee{
    id : number,
    name : String,
    age : number
}
```

I tried to solve this question using bellow link. But I couldn't get the answer for my question.

[Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073705/property-catch-does-not-exist-on-type-observableany)  and [Angular HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(…).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in-n/34515276#34515276)

Please give me some solution. Thank you.

Comment: it's because of pipeable/lettable operators which now angular is able to use tree-shakable and remove unused imports and optimize the app

some rxjs functions have  changed  ,  You may refer this article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196282/http-post-and-get-request-in-angular-6

Comment: If you carefully read the last answer in the first question that you linked, you should understand your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular 6 we use the rxjs 6 , your example correct for old version of angular  you may need to read more about rxjs 6

try this way

```
  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
               .pipe(catchError(this.handlerError));
   }
```

[catch / catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) ,
[RxJS 6 Changes](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)