# How can I call a restapi function from frontend (ejs/html)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to basically call the 'get' method from html/ejs when a button is pressed to query the database and display the results. Sorry if it's very simple, but I just can't get it work.

I tried to `require` the file and call the function inside a `script` tag but that doesn't work on the browser. I tried to add the js file with a `<script src="text/javascript" src="filename">` but that also results in errors. 
The rest API I built talks to oracle 11g (Toad) using `oracledb`.

I am basically trying to call the `get` function in this class

```
const employees = require('../db_apis/employees.js');

async function get(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const context = {};

        context.id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

        const rows = await employees.find(context);

        if (req.params.id) {
            if (rows.length === 1) {
                res.status(200).json(rows[0]);
            } else {
                res.status(404).end();
            }
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(rows);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
...
```

db_apis/employees.js

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const database = require('../services/database');

async function find(context) {
    const baseQuery =
    `SELECT *
    FROM choice_names`;
    console.log('in find');
    let query = baseQuery;
    const binds = {};
    let additionalQuery = '\nwhere ';

    if (context.id) {
        binds.choice_name = context.id;
        additionalQuery += `choice_name = :choice_name`;
        // query += `\nwhere choice_name = :choice_name`;
    } else if (context.user) {
        binds.choice_user = context.user;
        additionalQuery += `choice_user = :choice_user`;
    } else if (context.date) {
        binds.choice_date = context.date;
        additionalQuery += `choice_date = :choice_date`;
    }

    if (context.id || context.user || context.date) {
        query += additionalQuery;
    }
    console.log(query);
    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, binds);

    return result.rows;
}
...
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const employees = require('../controllers/employees');

router.route('/employees/:id?')
    .get(employees.get)
    .post(employees.post)
    .put(employees.put)
    .delete(employees.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs

```
...
<button onclick="get()">Click me</button>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are (very)confusing frontend and backend code.

The express app is in backend, running on some port, exposing the `/employees/:id` route.

But the frontend part doesn't have access to the backend scripts, So you need to do a XHR(Ajax) request from frontend to that route and get the result.

For example, in jQuery it can be something as

```
function get(){
   $.get('/employees/1').done(..do something..)
}
```

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196282/http-post-and-get-request-in-angular-6) on how to do it on angular.